# How to add a comment in sqlite3 init file .sqliterc

Tags: sqlite, comments, config

Is there a way to add a comment in the init file? The man page for sqlite3 doesn't mention any and I don't see any meta command that would suggest itself for such a purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put any of `sqlite3`s dot commands or any SQL commands into the init file.

So you can just use SQL comments:

```
/* Hello, world! */
-- line comment
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- single line comment

/* multiple
 * line
 * comment */
```

Be comfortable to add your comments in `.sqliterc` file , because it's a normal SQL query file